# Bundling Model and Services in MVC pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, mvc, patterns-and-practices

These days, all I hear is how MVC should contain additional layer called services, turning it into **S**MVC. But to me, it seems like too much of a decoupling and instead want to engineer my app something like this (example for changing user name)

> 1. View sends new input to Controller
> 2. Controller sends the request to Model with data it recieved to one central method of Model
> 3. Model takes this data and internally processes it with its methods, and returns the data to controller
> 4. Controller tells the View to update was completed and to update the View
> 5. View updates itself with data given by Controller

I have been told that Model should not directly work on data either and instead should use Service layers to handle the bussiness logic, so the flow would change like this

> 1. Controller sends the data to Model
> 2. Model calls respective Service to process the data
> 3. Model updates the data after Service processes them
>      Rest is the same

For me, the first solution seems more elegant and the later seems like making a Model another Controller with data relying on Services, which is kind of weird logic and adds another layer of complexity to the whole app.

Comment: have you got an example of where this service thign is suggested?

Answer (score 3):

The extra layer allows to be independent with respect to the data layer. That introduces flexibility, allowing a number of things, including:

- unit testing business logic, without data layer technology dependency
- support multiple data layers
- move to different data layer technology
- etc

Martin Fowler is much better at explaining this: https://martinfowler.com/bliki/PresentationDomainDataLayering.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading this [answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/162426/288295) on *How essential is it to make a service layer?* It states several reasons why you should implement a Service Layer. If you think that you don't need one, probably your use case is too simple.